# How do I convert hex string into byte string on Linux

Tags: linux, string, hex, byte

I would like to convert hex string into byte string on Linux using a bash script or a command. For instance, I would like to convert this hex string i.e. 00124a5b into a byte string i.e. \x00\x12\x4a\x5b

Thanks.

Plasma33

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the search replace functionality of `sed`:

```
echo "00124a5b" | sed 's/../\\x&/g'
\x00\x12\x4a\x5b
```

The two dots search for any two characters in the stream. The `\\x&` replaces the match with a `\x` followed by the match. Adding the g on end tells sed to continue the search/replace.

I would check out this tutorial for sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
There are several other tutorials on that site for other helpful commands.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks heaps for your input here and for a brief info. Plasma33